# Angular - secondary router outlet stays in URL when navigating to new tab/window

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router, angular13, router-outlet

I have a problem with angulars secondary router outlets (named outlets - https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets).

The issue I am facing is that whenever a named outlet is active Ex.:http://myRoute1(popup:myRoute2) and then I try to navigate to another route trought routerLink with ctrl/shift modifiers (new tab/window)... the named outlet just stays in the URL.

*Ex.: [routerLink]="['myOtherRoute']" produces an URL of http://myOtherRoute(popup:myRoute2) in new window/tab.*

Is there any way to omit this behaviour whitout writing custom URL serializer and then navigating trough window?

**EDIT: I forgot to point out that I DO want this behaviour when navigating inside the same tab!**

**SUMMARY:**

Solution like this deleted answer is not acceptable:

> [image]